How to output a .zip's filenames as raw bytes?
I have a .zip file whose filenames are not being correctly decoded and transcoded into unicode correctly.
While I do know what the filenames are meant to be, I don't know what encoding the .zip used for them. Is there an option I can pass to unzip to output the filenames as raw bytes (in hex)? Or is there any common programming language whose zip implementation would make this simple, rather than one which always uses its heuristics to try to transcode it for you?

The flag -U is meant for stopping the interpretation of UTF-8, but might work for you?

I have a program called zipdetails that dumps the full metadata of a zip file. The part that will interest you is it include an optional ASCII hex dump of all the items of metadata, including the filename.
For example, create a zip file with a UTF-8 filename
$ echo abcd >Café 

$ zip -X test.zip Café  
  adding: Café (stored 0%)

Dump the contents
$ perl zipdetails -v test.zip
0000 0004 50 4B 03 04 LOCAL HEADER #1       04034B50
0004 0001 0A          Extract Zip Spec      0A '1.0'
0005 0001 00          Extract OS            00 'MS-DOS'
0006 0002 00 08       General Purpose Flag  0800
                      [Bit 11]              1 'Language Encoding'
0008 0002 00 00       Compression Method    0000 'Stored'
000A 0004 58 AD F5 58 Last Mod Time         58F5AD58 'Sun Jul 21 22:42:48 2024'
000E 0004 AC A4 8A 58 CRC                   588AA4AC
0012 0004 05 00 00 00 Compressed Length     00000005
0016 0004 05 00 00 00 Uncompressed Length   00000005
001A 0002 05 00       Filename Length       0005
001C 0002 00 00       Extra Length          0000
001E 0005 43 61 66 C3 Filename              'Café'
          A9
...

You can use the --encoding option to tell zipdetails what encoding to use when it displays the filename. Note that this will not change the ASCII hex values shown for the filename.

That looks perfect, thanks!

It can be a little bit off topic, but I recently had an issue where I encoded everything on Windows and then needed to unpack it on Mac. So all the filenames were written with different hieroglyphs.
For such an issue there was also a question: How can I correctly decompress a ZIP archive of files with Hebrew names?
And to myself personally helped this app: https://en.bandisoft.com/bandizip.mac/
Free of use for 7 days (no paying information needed, I just extracted everything). Nothing else was working, and this app did autodetect the encoding
Maybe if you have enough space, you could extract your .zip archive using right encoding just like I did
